# filter JSON when running raking task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am trying to filter my rake task by vehicles with the make 'jeep'. I have written: `if posting["make"] = "jeep"` but it seems all car data is being pulled, not just cars with the make `"jeep"` ....

`"jeep"` is an annotation value for the data pulled from the API. when running this rake task I am getting all vehicle makes, including jeep.

```
 namespace :scraper do
 desc "Fetch Craigslist posts from 3Taps"
 task scrape: :environment do
 require 'open-uri'
 require 'json'


# Set API token and URL
auth_token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
polling_url = "http://polling.3taps.com/poll"


# Specify request parameters
params = {
  auth_token: auth_token,
  anchor: 1900885490,
  source:"CRAIG",
  category_group: "VVVV",
  category: "VAUT",
  'location.city' => "USA-PIT-PIT",
  retvals: "location,external_url,heading,body,timestamp,price,images,annotations"

}

# Prepare API request
uri = URI.parse(polling_url)
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(params)

# Submit request
result = JSON.parse(open(uri).read)

# Display results to screen
#puts JSON.pretty_generate result["postings"].first
#end
# #store results in Database
result["postings"].each do |posting|

#ADD HARD FILTER (IN PROGRESS....)
if posting["make"] == "Jeep"

#create new post
@post= Post.new
@post.heading = posting["heading"]
@post.body = posting["body"]
@post.price = posting["price"]
@post.neighborhood = Location.find_by(code: posting["location"]["locality"]).try(:name)
@post.external_url = posting["external_url"]
@post.timestamp = posting["timestamp"]
@post.year = posting ["annotations"]["year"] if posting ["annotations"]["year"].present? 
@post.make = posting ["annotations"]["make"] if posting ["annotations"]["make"].present? 
@post.model = posting ["annotations"]["model"] if posting ["annotations"]["model"].present? 
@post.title_status = posting ["annotations"]["title_status"] if posting ["annotations"]["title_status"].present? 
@post.transmission = posting ["annotations"]["transmission"] if posting ["annotations"]["transmission"].present? 
@post.mileage = posting ["annotations"]["mileage"] if posting ["annotations"]["mileage"].present? 


#Save Post
@post.save

#Loop over images and save to image database
posting["images"].each do |image|
  @image = Image.new
  @image.url = image["full"]
  @image.post_id = @post.id
  @image.save
    end
      end
        end

  desc "Destroy All Posting Data"
  task destroy_all_posts: :environment do
    Post.destroy_all
  end


###save neighborhoods
 desc "Save neighborhood codes in a reference table"
  task scrape_neighborhoods: :environment do
    require 'open-uri'
    require 'json'


# Set API token and URL
auth_token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
location_url = "http://reference.3taps.com/locations"


# Specify request parameters
params = {
  auth_token: auth_token,
  level: "locality",
  city: "USA-PIT-PIT"

}

# Prepare API request
uri = URI.parse(location_url)
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(params)

# Submit request
result = JSON.parse(open(uri).read)

# Display results to screen
#puts JSON.pretty_generate result

# store results in Database
result["locations"].each do |location|
  @location = Location.new
  @location.code = location["code"]
  @location.name = location["short_name"]
  @location.save
end 
end
end 
end
```

Comment: ahhh okay, I will give this a try.....THANK YOU! -I will post back with results

Comment: i am now getting an error: dont know how to build task scraper:scrape ?

Comment: ok-- I updated the post to show the whole code...can you take a look and let me know....

Comment: Still not able to get this to work , sorry I'm a kinda a new.

Comment: Yes it  has a .rake extension. .. The rake was running successfully before I put the == so not sure why I'm getting the error now..

Comment: That is weird, are you sure you didn't change anything else? Changing the operator `=` shouldn't have made it stop working. If you change it back to `=` does it start working again?

Comment: I'll try and report back

Comment: ok not sure what the issue was -- reverted to an old code and ran the rake and everything worked - I then added if posting["make"] == "jeep" which ran (((although I didnt get any results..a least the rake ran)))

Comment: do you think I need:  if posting["annotations"]["make"] == "jeep"

Comment: SOLVED! I am now just pulling the data I need THANK YOU! :):)

Comment: I posted the answer and deleted the comments because it was too polluted. If you would accept it I would appreciate. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are using the assignment operator `=` instead of the equal comparison `==` in `if posting["make"] = "Jeep"`.

After that, you needed to change the if to `if posting["annotations"]["make"] == "jeep"` because the data returned by the server is nested. The key `make` is under `annotations`.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace :scraper do
  desc "Fetch Craigslist posts from 3Taps"
  task scrape: :environment do
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'


# Set API token and URL
auth_token = "@@"
polling_url = "http://polling.3taps.com/poll"


# Specify request parameters
params = {
  auth_token: auth_token,
  anchor: 1900885490,
  source:"CRAIG",
  category_group: "VVVV",
  category: "VAUT",
  'location.city' => "USA-PIT-PIT",
  retvals: "location,external_url,heading,body,timestamp,price,images,annotations"

}

# Prepare API request
uri = URI.parse(polling_url)
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(params)

# Submit request
result = JSON.parse(open(uri).read)

# Display results to screen
#puts result["postings"].first["annotations"]["year"]

# #store results in Database
result["postings"].each do |posting|





 if posting["annotations"]["make"] == "Jeep"

#create new post
@post= Post.new
@post.heading = posting["heading"]
@post.body = posting["body"]
@post.price = posting["price"]
@post.neighborhood = posting["location"]["locality"]
@post.external_url = posting["external_url"]
@post.timestamp = posting["timestamp"]
@post.year = posting ["annotations"]["year"] if posting ["annotations"]["year"].present? 
@post.make = posting ["annotations"]["make"] if posting ["annotations"]["make"].present? 
@post.model = posting ["annotations"]["model"] if posting ["annotations"]["model"].present? 
@post.title_status = posting ["annotations"]["title_status"] if posting ["annotations"]["title_status"].present? 
@post.transmission = posting ["annotations"]["transmission"] if posting ["annotations"]["transmission"].present? 
@post.mileage = posting ["annotations"]["mileage"] if posting ["annotations"]["mileage"].present? 


#Save Post
@post.save

# Loop over images and save to Image database
    posting["images"].each do |image|
      @image = Image.new
      @image.url = image["full"]
      @image.post_id = @post.id 
      @image.save
 end  
  end
    end
      end


  desc "Destroy All Posting Data"
  task destroy_all_posts: :environment do
    Post.destroy_all
  end

end
```